# Tangents to the curve $y=x^3-3x^2-7x+6$ cut off on the negative semi axis $OX$ a line segment half that on the positive semi axis $OY$ is

Tags: calculus

The coordinates of points at each of which the tangents to the curve $y=x^3-3x^2-7x+6$ cut off on the negative semi axis $OX$ a line segment half that on the positive semi axis $OY$ is/are given by
$(A)(-1,9)$
$(B)(3,-15)$
$(C)(1,-3)$
$(D)$none

---

Let the point of tangency be $(x_1,y_1)$
Then the equation of tangent is $\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=3x_1^2-6x_1-7$
I am stuck here.

Comment: Is the semi-axis $OX$ *perpendicular* to the semi-axis $OY$?

Comment: yes it is perpendicular.

Comment: Please include that information in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the point of tangency be $(x_1,y_1)$
Then the equation of tangent is $\displaystyle\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=3x_1^2-6x_1-7$.

When $y=0$, $\displaystyle x=x_1+\frac{-y_1}{3x_1^2-6x_1-7}$.

When $x=0$, $\displaystyle y=y_1-x_1(3x_1^2-6x_1-7)$.

\begin{align}
-2\left(x_1+\frac{-y_1}{3x_1^2-6x_1-7}\right)&=y_1-x_1(3x_1^2-6x_1-7)\\
-2\left(\frac{x_1(3x_1^2-6x_1-7)-y_1}{3x_1^2-6x_1-7}\right)&=y_1-x_1(3x_1^2-6x_1-7)\\
2&=3x_1^2-6x_1-7\\
3x_1^2-6x_1-9&=0\\
x_1&=-1\quad\text{or}\quad3
\end{align}

When $x_1=-1$, $y_1=(-1)^3-3(-1)^2-7(-1)+6=9$ and the $y$-intercept is

$$9-(-1)[3(-1)^2-6(-1)-7]=11>0$$

When $x_1=3$, $y_1=(3)^3-3(3)^2-7(3)+6=-15$ and the $y$-intercept is

$$-15-(3)[3(3)^2-6(3)-7]=-21<0$$

So, the point of tangency is $(-1,9)$.

Comment: Isn't the answer (3,-15)? The y intercept of the tangent the other one implies is wrong.

Comment: The tangent at (-1,9) meets the x-axis at (-5.5,0) and meets the y-axis at (0,11), exactly as what we need.

The tangent at (3,-15) meets the x-axis at (10.5,0) and meets the y-axis at (0,-21). The signs are opposite to what required in the question.